# reading address bar of browser using java

Tags: java

I want to generate a complete record of all the urls visited in a session using java. How to do that?

Comment: Do "all the urls" include sites outside of your domain?

Answer (score 1):

Practical approach - use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to record the complete traffic to a logfile and write a Java application that reads the file and extracts all URLs.

You may have to filter the result list to limit the URLs to the URLs actually entered in an address bar. Otherwise you'll get the full list, including referenced URLs from loaded documents.

Answer (score 0):

if we talk about server-side programming, than (if you use jsf/spring_webflow, know only these two) you could try to put listeners in it, so every request will leave it's url in some kind of Collecion.